# Materializecss navbar logo image position

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am having issues with positioning my custom image logo I want it to be perfectly centered in the navbar however it's a bit off in the mobile view and desktop view. [Mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZOo0.jpg)

The desktop version is also a bit off I tried using `vertical-align: middle;` but it's not doing its job properly.

Example:

```css
.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}

.logo>img {
    vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative; 
    top:1px; 
}
```

```html
  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    
   <div class="navbar-fixed">
  <nav class="blue darken-1">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
     <a href="#Main" class="logo">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/sFliVuL.png" >
        </a> <a class="sidenav-trigger" data-target="mobile-demo" href="#"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
     <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li>
       <a class="waves-effect" href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a class="waves-effect" href="#info">Info</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a class="waves-effect" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a class="waves-effect" href="#links">Social</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
 </div>
 <ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
  <li class="user-view">
   <div class="background"><img alt="tokyo" src="img/navmenu.jpg"></div>
   <div class="wow zoomIn"><img alt="me" class="circle" src="img/me.jpg"></div><a href="#"><span class="white-text name">Edgar</span></a> <a href="mailto:edgar@teamhusky.net"><span class="white-text email">edgar@teamhusky.net</span></a>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vertical-align: middle` only works on elements with `display: table-cell`. However, there are a few better ways.

Try using absolute positioning combined with a transform to vertically center:

```css
.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}

.logo>img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    
   <div class="navbar-fixed">
  <nav class="blue darken-1">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
     <a href="#Main" class="logo">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/sFliVuL.png" >
        </a> <a class="sidenav-trigger" data-target="mobile-demo" href="#"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
     <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li>
       <a class="waves-effect" href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a class="waves-effect" href="#info">Info</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a class="waves-effect" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a class="waves-effect" href="#links">Social</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
 </div>
 <ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
  <li class="user-view">
   <div class="background"><img alt="tokyo" src="img/navmenu.jpg"></div>
   <div class="wow zoomIn"><img alt="me" class="circle" src="img/me.jpg"></div><a href="#"><span class="white-text name">Edgar</span></a> <a href="mailto:edgar@teamhusky.net"><span class="white-text email">edgar@teamhusky.net</span></a>
  </li>
```